# SQL logic to achieve the below mentioned scenario

Tags: sql

I would like to know about the SQL logic to achieve the below scenario.

From the source I need to load the data to target as described below.

Source

```
ID  Name    Place       Date
1   User 1  Chennai     01-Jun-22
1   User 1  Chennai     02-Jun-22
2   User 2  Bangalore   03-Jun-22
2   User 2  Bangalore   04-Jun-22
1   User 1  Bangalore   05-Jun-22
1   User 1  Bangalore   06-Jun-22
1   User 1  Bangalore   07-Jun-22
1   User 1  Chennai     08-Jun-22
```

Target

```
ID  Name    Place       From Date   To Date
1   User 1  Chennai     01-Jun-22   02-Jun-22
2   User 2  Bangalore   03-Jun-22   04-Jun-22
1   User 1  Bangalore   05-Jun-22   07-Jun-22
1   User 1  Chennai     08-Jun-22   08-Jun-22
```

Comment: Kindly read about MIN and MAX function and let us know what you tried.

Comment: Hello Nishant, Sorry I updated the question now. Earlier I posted incomplete question. Please review the question now.

Comment: Kindly provide the name of the SQL platform along with version you are using. Also, why Chennai in the end is not considered with the Chennai data in the first row in Target?

Comment: We can consider platform as Oracle (any version). Basically the source data is something like " User is moving from one place to another and staying in that location for N number of days". From this data set I need to derive an information like, from which date to other dats user was residing in the particular place. As described in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your problem:

```
WITH CT1 AS
(
SELECT ID, Name, Place, "Date",
CASE WHEN CONCAT(ID,Place) != LAG(CONCAT(ID,Place),1,'0') OVER(ORDER BY "Date") THEN 1 ELSE 0END as t
FROM Table1
),
CT2 AS
(
SELECT ID, Name, Place, "Date",
SUM(t) OVER(ORDER BY "Date") as grp
FROM CT1
)
SELECT ID, Name, Place,
MIN("Date") as From_Date,
MAX("Date") as To_Date
FROM CT2
GROUP BY ID, Name, Place,grp
ORDER BY From_Date;
```

Working Example : [db<>fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd05370168ba8bca6080a13779195df2)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp([ID] INT,[Name] VARCHAR(100),[Place] VARCHAR(100),[Date] DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #Temp([ID],[Name],[Place],[Date]) VALUES('1','User1','Chennai','01-06-2022')
INSERT INTO #Temp([ID],[Name],[Place],[Date]) VALUES('1','User1','Chennai','02-06-2022')
INSERT INTO #Temp([ID],[Name],[Place],[Date]) VALUES('2','User2','Bangalore','03-06-2022')
INSERT INTO #Temp([ID],[Name],[Place],[Date]) VALUES('2','User2','Bangalore','04-06-2022')
INSERT INTO #Temp([ID],[Name],[Place],[Date]) VALUES('1','User1','Bangalore','05-06-2022')
INSERT INTO #Temp([ID],[Name],[Place],[Date]) VALUES('1','User1','Bangalore','06-06-2022')
INSERT INTO #Temp([ID],[Name],[Place],[Date]) VALUES('1','User1','Bangalore','07-06-2022')
INSERT INTO #Temp([ID],[Name],[Place],[Date]) VALUES('1','User1','Chennai','08-06-2022')


;WITH A AS(
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) [Rono],
*,
LEAD([Name]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) LeadName,
LEAD([Place]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) LeadPlace,
LAG([Name]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) LagName,
LAG([Place]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) LagPlace,

CASE WHEN LEAD([Name]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date])=[Name] AND LEAD([Place]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date])=[Place] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END F1,
CASE WHEN LAG([Name]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date])=[Name] AND LAG([Place]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date])=[Place] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END F2
FROM #Temp
),
B AS(
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN (A.F1=1 AND A.F2=0) OR (A.F1=0 AND A.F2=0) THEN LEAD([Rono]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) WHEN (A.F1=1 AND A.F2=1) THEN NULL ELSE 0 END [FF]
FROM A 
WHERE A.F1+A.F2!=2
)
SELECT 
B.[ID],B.[Name],B.[Place],
B.[Date] [StrtDate],
ISNULL(AB.[Date],B.[Date]) [EndDate]
FROM B
LEFT JOIN B AB ON B.FF=AB.Rono
WHERE B.FF!=0 OR B.FF IS NULL
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).